# Time-Continuity of PCA/SVD

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd

I have a daily set of observations ([Jacard similarity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)) that I want to embed in a much lower dimensional space.

Thus I run [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA) or [SVD](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) for each day and plot the projection on the top 2 dimensions (they usually explain ~90% of variance, but this is beyond the point).

My **problem** is that when I animate the embedding, I see that it ***flips*** along the 2nd coordinate every now and then, i.e., the embedding is ***not*** time-continuous.

I wonder what can be done to *ensure* time-continuity.

E.g., using a "running average" of, say, 3 days of data might *improve* continuity, but is unlikely to *ensure* it.

Comment: See the discussion in:
Keane, Kevin R., and Jason J. Corso. "Maintaining prior distributions across evolving eigenspaces: An application to portfolio construction." 2012 11th International Conference on Machine Learning and Applications. Vol. 2. IEEE, 2012.


https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jason-Corso/publication/235916864_Maintaining_Prior_Distributions_across_Evolving_Eigenspaces_An_Application_to_Portfolio_Construction/links/0deec518bbb414a15b000000/Maintaining-Prior-Distributions-across-Evolving-Eigenspaces-An-Application-to-Portfolio-Construction.pdf